# Does exists a Linux distro that run on an AllWinner A10S cpu?

Tags: distributions

I've just bought a mini pc (a T004 Auxtek) but I would like to run a Linux distro on it so I can use as mini server Linux. Do you know if exists an AllWinner A10s distro for this type of mini PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES -- from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allwinner_A1X):

> The Allwinner A1X, **known under Linux as sunxi,** is a family of
>   single-core SoC devices designed by Allwinner Technology from Zhuhai,
>   China. Currently the family consists of the A10,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allwinner_A1X) A13,[2](http://linux-sunxi.org/Main_Page) A10s[3](http://linux-sunxi.org/Category:Linux_Distributions)
>   and A12. The SoCs incorporate the ARM Cortex-A8 as their main
>   processor and the Mali 400 as the GPU.
>
> The Allwinner A1X is **known for its ability to boot GNU/Linux
>   distributions such as Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, and other ARM
>   architecture-capable distributions** from an SD card, in addition to the
>   Android OS usually installed on the flash memory of the device.

It's currently not in the vanilla kernel's ARM ports, however.  But following [a link](http://linux-sunxi.org/Main_Page) from the wikipedia page, I found [a list of linux distributions](http://linux-sunxi.org/Category:Linux_Distributions) apparently using a kernel compiled with the sunxi patches.  GCC includes a number of `arm7` options (ARMv7 being the processor family), which is what makes all this fundamentally possible, including the userspace.

There are various A10 devices advertised by the distributor as "Linux/GNU capable", some of which may even include a distribution.  If so, those images may be available for free.

Beware that the "Cortex-A8" is still an ARMv7 style processor, like the "Cortex-A7", and *not* an ARMv8 style. The CPU in the A10 is a Cortex-A8.

Answer (score 0):

No as I know, but you could try search in Archlinux ARM forum board: http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=33

There is possibility that very similar boards distribution might work, because you want to have mini server, if say some graphic accelerator or x server wont work that would be no problem.